# H2o GLM interact only certain predictors

Tags: r, glm, h2o, one-hot-encoding

I'm interested in creating interaction terms in h2o.glm().  But I do not want to generate all pairwise interactions.  For example, in the mtcars dataset...I want to interact 'mpg' with all the other factors such as 'cyl','hp', and 'disp' but I don't want the other factors to interact with each other (so I don't want disp_hp or disp_cyl).

How should I best approach this problem using the (interactions = interactions_list) parameter in h2o.glm() ?

Thank you

Comment: @DarrenCook I don't see a straightforward way to do this within the arguments of `h2o.glm()`, but below is a workaround to suppress unwanted interaction terms.

Comment: Update: h2o now has an interactions_terms parameter that solves this issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `?h2o.glm` the `interactions=`  parameter takes:

> A list of predictor column indices to interact. All
>   pairwise combinations will be computed for the list.

You do not want all pairwise combinations, only specific ones.

Unfortunately, the R H2O API does not provide a formula interface.  If it did, then an arbitrary set of interactions would be possible to specify programatically, as in a vanilla R glm.<sup>1</sup>

### Option 1: Use `beta_constraints`

One solution is to include **all** pairwise combinations in the model and then **suppress** those you do not want by setting the betas equal to 0.

According to the [glm docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html), `beta_constraints=` serves to:

> Specify a dataset to use beta constraints. The selected frame is used
>   to constraint the coefficient vector to provide upper and lower
>   bounds. The dataset must contain a names column with valid coefficient
>   names.

According to the [H2O Glossary](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/glossary.html), the format for `beta_constraints` is:

> A data.frame or H2OParsedData object with the columns [“names”,
>   “lower_bounds”,”upper_bounds”, “beta_given”], where each row
>   corresponds to a predictor in the GLM. “names” contains the predictor
>   names, “lower_bounds” and “upper_bounds” are the lower and upper
>   bounds of beta, and “beta_given” is some supplied starting values for
>   beta.

Now we know how to fill out our `beta_constraints` data frame **except** for how to format the interaction term names.  The [doc on interactions](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/interactions.html) doesn't tell us what to expect. 
 So let's just run an example with interactions through H2O and see what the interactions get named.

```
library('h2o')
remoteH2O <- h2o.init(ip='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', startH2O=FALSE)

data(mtcars)

df1 <- as.h2o(mtcars, destination_frame = 'demo_mtcars')

target <- 'wt'
predictors <- c('mpg','cyl','hp','disp')

glm1 <- h2o.glm(x = predictors,
                y = target,
                training_frame = 'demo_mtcars',
                model_id = 'demo_glm',
                lambda = 0, # disable regularization, but your use case may vary
                standardize = FALSE, # we want to see the raw parameters, but your use case may vary
                interactions = predictors # create all interactions
                )
print(glm1) # output includes:
# Coefficients: glm coefficients
#        names coefficients
# 1  Intercept     4.336269
# 2    mpg_cyl     0.019558
# 3     mpg_hp     0.000156
# ..
```

So it looks like the interaction terms are getting named like `v1_v2`.

So let's name all the interaction terms we want to suppress, using `setdiff()` against the terms we want to keep.

```
library(tidyr)
intx_terms_keep <- # see footnote 1 for explanation
  expand.grid(c('mpg'),c('cyl','hp','disp')) %>%
    unite(intx, Var1, Var2, sep='_') %>% unlist()

intx_terms_suppress <- setdiff( # suppress all interactions minus those we wish to keep
                             combn(predictors,2,FUN=paste,collapse='_'), 
                             intx_terms_keep
                            )
constraints <- data.frame(names=intx_terms_suppress, 
                          lower_bounds=0, 
                          upper_bounds=0, 
                          beta_given=0)

glm2 <- h2o.glm(x = predictors,
                y = target,
                training_frame = 'demo_mtcars',
                model_id = 'demo_glm',
                lambda = 0,
                standardize = FALSE, 
                interactions = predictors, # create all interactions
                beta_constraints = constraints
)
print(glm2) # output includes:
# Coefficients: glm coefficients
#        names coefficients
# 1  Intercept     3.405154
# 2    mpg_cyl    -0.012740
# 3     mpg_hp    -0.000250
# 4   mpg_disp     0.000066
# 5     cyl_hp     0.000000
# 6   cyl_disp     0.000000
# 7    hp_disp     0.000000
# 8        mpg    -0.018981
# 9        cyl     0.168820
# 10      disp     0.004070
# 11        hp     0.000501
```

As you can see, only the desired interaction terms have non-zero coefficients.  The rest are effectively ignored.  **However,** since they are still terms in the model, they may count towards degrees of freedom and may affect some of the metrics (i.e., adjusted R-squared).

### Option 2: pre-create the interaction terms

As @Darren Cook mentioned, another solution would be to pre-create the interactions as variables in the training dataset.

This approach would ensure that the unwanted interactions do not count towards degrees of freedom and impact your adjusted R-squared.

#### <sup>1</sup> Alternative, non-H2O solution for vanilla `glm` formula interface

In a vanilla R `glm()`, which allows the formula interface, I would use `expand.grid` to create a string of interaction terms and include it in the formula.

Pass `expand.grid` two vectors -- you want to interact all terms in v1 with all terms in v2.

To use your example, you want to interact `mpg` with `cyl`, `hp`, and `disp`:

```
library(tidyr)
intx_term_string <- 
  expand.grid(c('mpg'),c('cyl','hp','disp')) %>%
    unite(intx, Var1, Var2, sep=':') %>% apply(2, paste, collapse='+')
```

This gives you a string of interaction terms like `"mpg:cyl+mpg:hp+mpg:disp"` that you can paste into a string of other predictors (possibly using paste-collapse) and convert with `as.formula()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can't believe such simple functionality still doesn't exist in H2O.

Comment: I think that using formulas in h2o.glm would make implementing the deta_constraints very complicated, because the constraints refer explicitly to the variables that are constrained. You can create a formula as @C8H10N4O2 suggests, and then create the design matrix X in R using X = model.matrix( ~ formula , data=mydata). Use X in the h2o.glm call.