# Beta constraints in H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator

Tags: pyspark, glm, h2o

I'm looking for a way to set beta in prior to the model run in H2O GeneralizedLinearEstimator? Beta which can be used as a starting point for the model? It is called beta constraints as per the documentation below. Could someone help me with this.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/beta_constraints.html

#### Here is the example what I'm trying

1)   Model 1: I ran a model with 20 iterations and used the betas from this model run and saved it as a data frame

2)   Model 2: I ran a model with everything the same as the first Model (including 20 iterations), additionally I specified beta constraints as the coefficient from the previous model. Trying to warm start this model so it starts where the previous model ended.

3)   Model 3: I ran a model with everything the same as the first model but with 40 iteration

As explained in the documentation I wanted to compare and see that the model 2 betas to be same as the betas from a model 3

#### Code with beta constraints specification

```
    model2 =  H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family = "poisson",
                                            alpha=0,
                                            solver = "L-BFGS", 
                                            max_iterations=20, 
                                            gradient_epsilon=1e-8, 
                                            objective_epsilon=1e-8, 
                                            beta_epsilon=1e-8, 
                                            beta_constraints=bc)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [H2O Glossary](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/glossary.html), the format for `beta_constraints` is:

> A data.frame or H2OParsedData object with the columns [“names”,
>   “lower_bounds”,”upper_bounds”, “beta_given”], where each row
>   corresponds to a predictor in the GLM. “names” contains the predictor
>   names, “lower_bounds” and “upper_bounds” are the lower and upper
>   bounds of beta, and “beta_given” is some supplied starting values for
>   beta.

First, you need to get the vector of betas from Model 2. Call them `m2_betas`.

Next, because you want strict equality constraints, you need to and set those to the upper bounds, lower bounds, **and** starting value.

I have done this in R (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641157/2573061)), where `beta_constraints` are passed as a `data.frame` but I assume that the Python API is similar and uses a `pandas.DataFrame`. Try:

```
constraints = pd.DataFrame({'names':x.columns, 
                             'lower_bounds':m2_betas, 
                             'upper_bounds':m2_betas, 
                             'beta_given':m2_betas})
```

Comment: Hi, I used this technique it changes the beta after defining the beta constraints, but not giving me the desired results I'm looking for as per my question above.

Comment: This is how I defined beta constraints

Comment: names  beta_given  lower_bounds  upper_bounds

Comment: Intercept      -4.455417     -4.455417     -4.455417

Comment: 23_22_NA   -1.959672     -1.959672     -1.959672

Comment: 16_3_NA    -3.796567     -3.796567     -3.796567

Comment: (this section doesn't support table format, so specifying it individual lines)